# Insert or Update only Particular Record using Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, database-trigger

I am trying to insert record into table B if there is any Update/Insert in Table A. Trigger should insert only the record in the insert statement and not all the table records in Table A to Table B. Your help is highly appreciated.

Code is working fine but its trying to insert all the records in the table A instead of only the particular record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger  
ON dbo.Test 
FOR INSERT,update 
as

  insert into dbo.TestBKP(ID, LastName, FirstName, Age, updatetime)
    select ID, LastName, FirstName, Age, getdate()
    from Test

  print 'Row Inserted';

GO

insert into dbo.Test values(1,'AAA','BBB',24)
```

**Expectation**

dbo.TestBKP table should contains only the above insert values and not all the data in the dbo.Test values.

Comment: Change `from Test` to `from Inserted`

Comment: You should use the `inserted` pseudo table.

Comment: You are using  `table A` and `table B` but it is not included from your code.

Comment: Thanks @DaleBurrell for your comment and it helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using triggers (and `OUTPUT` clause on `SELECT` or `MERGE` statements), there's a special keyword table called `inserted` that holds the records of the tracking table being inserted or updated. You need to reference this table if you just want to work with these records, and not the whole tracking table, as your example (`FROM dbo.Test`).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON dbo.Test 
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    insert into dbo.TestBKP (
        ID, 
        LastName, 
        FirstName, 
        Age, 
        updatetime)
    select 
        ID, 
        LastName, 
        FirstName, 
        Age, 
        getdate()
    from 
        inserted AS I -- This "inserted" table is a copy of dbo.Test with only new/updated records

    print 'Row Inserted';

END
```

When coding an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` triggers, there's another keyword special table called `deleted` that holds the deleted rows (when triggered by a `DELETE`) or the old versions of the updated rows (when triggered by an `UPDATE`).

Answer (score 0):

just replace Test to Inserted on select statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON dbo.Test
FOR INSERT
AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.TestBKP
     (ID, 
      LastName, 
      FirstName, 
      Age, 
      updatetime
     )
            SELECT ID, 
                   LastName, 
                   FirstName, 
                   Age, 
                   GETDATE()
            FROM **inserted**;
     PRINT 'Row Inserted';
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES
(1, 
 'AAA', 
 'BBB', 
 24
);
```